# Jetty Server using the same session for all requests from different browsers in a Restful application

Tags: java, jetty, jax-rs, cxf

Jetty server using the same session for all the requests from different browsers.

Is it the default Jetty behaviour for session, Or do we need to change the configuration for the Session ?
Can you please explain?

Comment: I am not sure of your issue. Do you mean the same SessionID is being shared among browsers?

Comment: yes, I am printing the session Id after creating the session. The requests from 2 different browsers printing the same session id.

Comment: There must be some mistake. The sessions have to be different between users and browsers. What are you printing? (add the code) Check also the value of JSESSIONID cookie at client side

Comment: `HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
   logger.info("Session Id::::"+session.getId());
   logger.info("Cookie Name::::"+session.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().getName());`

Comment: Open the browser inspector to see the value of JSESSIONID cookie in each browser. It should be different. Check also the url and cookies thar the client is sending to server. Are you using urlrewritting?(Your url is like this  `url;jsessionid=...`)